# Default Dota 2 config.cfg file?

Tags: dota-2

Where can I find the **default** Dota 2 **config.cfg** file? Also, is my current **config.cfg** file identical to the default one when I first installed the game, or is it changed based on what settings I've changed in the in-game menu? I've heard people say that no matter what you change, changes are temporary, just for that session and they are all gone/back to default once you close the game. Question is what is the default, how can I see what the default is? And where is it stored? Hopefully I've made myself clear.

Comment: What do you see when you edit your config.cfg with a basic notepad ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm sure I know what you're talking about.
First off head to: Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg
You might already know that but there's your config.cfg

Your current config.cfg **will** be altered by your settings ingame though.

Keep in mind that most of the settings altered by your autoexec.cfg file or even the temporary settings done via ingame menu will be set back to default **if you delete your config.cfg and restart the game**.

Again, it's "most of your settings" as the **keybinds will prevail** thanks to the Steam Cloud.

Comment: So what does Steam Cloud actually possess? The pure default config.cfg file (the one that comes with the fresh install of the game) or what? Question is, where can I find the DEFAULT (the one that comes with a fresh install) config.cfg file, not a changed/modificated one.

Comment: The config.cfg is recreated by the DotA 2 itself I believe, only personal settings are preserved (like keybindings), so since they are "borrowed" from the Steam Cloud, right clicking DotA in steam, choosing properties and disabling the Steam Cloud in a proper tab should do the trick. That should _really_ bring your config to default.

Comment: So I should 
1. Delete config.cfg
2. Disable Steam Cloud
3. Open the game (this creates a fresh new config.cfg file)
4. Enable Steam Cloud again so it can replace the old one with the one on my PC?

Comment: If you enable the Steam Cloud you will get your bindings back. Usually it should just tell you there is a conflict and let you choose which version of your files it's going to use (cloud or local). This is not the case as instead it often just forces the cloud settings over the local files without asking. This is a known issue, you should consider reading this: 
[Method to delete Steam Cloud files](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784)

Comment: So I guess, Steam Cloud is not needed unless you are playing on different machines..

Comment: The autoexec settings won't be applied after a restart? Strange. Maybe because the creation of a new conf file is done after executing autoexec